# Jaspersoft: 4.2.1 upgrade creates issues with olap access grant schemas

Tags: jasperserver, mondrian

We are in the process of developing all our domains, olap schemas, reports, etc....in preparation for a Q1 launch of jasper replacing an older BI suite. We had been working in 4.1 and had a working environment with users that had JIProfileAttributes and passing these attributes in filters for both Domains and OLAP connections via access grants. This was all working correctly in 4.1 applying data security where necessary. We recently upgraded the server to 4.2.1 as there were some additional features we wanted to take advantage of for our development but it appears the upgrade broke the security for the OLAP. None of the profile attributes are applying any filters within OLAP after the upgrade. They ARE still working with domains.....just the OLAP that broke. Wondering if anyone else has had a similar issue with 4.2.1. Have a ticket opened with Jaspersupport but have not gotten any feedback on this yet. Unfortunately it has stalled some of our development as data security needs to be tested and this piece simply no longer works. I have tried re-doing the upgrade to make sure that was done correctly and also tried simply reloading the olap schema, connection and access grant but still not working in 4.2.1. Any feedback would be appreciated. At this point I'd settle for at least knowing it's a `known issue` and will be addressed ASAP. Luckily we are still in development else this would have been a major issue for us. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's a known issue and will be addressed ASAP.

You should hear back directly from Jaspersoft Technical Support as well. I suppose they'll have more info about when a patch is expected.

Answer (score 0):

I came across an issue recently with roles and permissions behaving very strangely. Eventually found out the problem was down to that I had two JasperReport Server instances running on my development PC, and that JasperReports Server actually stores in cache files information about access control lists (as well as other things). I found that one instance of JRS was incorrectly picking up the ACL cache of the other, causing all sorts of problems.
I found that bringing down each server, deleting the cache files, and then only running one server at a time (remembering to delete the files between bouncing) solved all issues.
I'm just thinking, reading your problem, that may be you've installed the upgrade either over the top of the existing install, or in a different directory, but it is picking up the previous install old cache files and causing these problems.
As I'm developing on Windows I found the cache files under C:\Users\my.profile\AppData\Local\Temp\ehcache and C:\Users\my.profile\AppData\Local\Temp\ehcache-hibernate. I don't know where on Linux/Unix this may be stored, but I think it uses the Java environment variable java.io.tmpdir.
Hope this helps..